# Hide ojPagingControl if there is no data to show in Ojet

Tags: oracle-jet

If there is no data to show in ojTable I want to hide the table and pagination. I can able to hide the ojTable but not the pagination. How can I hide the pagingcontrol if there is no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a KO virtual binding around the pagination element.

Something like this:

```
<!-- ko if: pagingDatasource.dataSource.data.length == '0' -->
<div id="paging" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojPagingControl', data: 
 pagingDatasource, pageSize: 15}">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

With the above code, if the length is zero, the paging element won't be added to the DOM at all.